# Eclipse C/C++ - MercurialEclipse is not listed to install

Tags: eclipse, ns-3, mercurialeclipse

According to given instructions online, I am trying to install MercurialEclipse to setup my NS3 application on Eclipse Oxygen. However, I can't find this plugin under "http://cbes.javaforge.com/update" location.

[image]

Comment: Q: Did you get this squared away?  If not, what are you actually trying to do?  Is getting the MercurialEclipse plugin working really essential to your end goal?

Answer (score 1):

Try looking here:

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/mercurialeclipse

You should be able to do a "Drag Install" using the [Install] Button.

See also:

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/codebeamer-eclipse-studio

Comment: Using this method, it seems "mercurial is not correctly installed". This is the error I get when I right click on my project and click on "team -> share project -> mercurial". Also, when I restart Eclipse, I get a popup error which says "Multiple Mercurial error have occurred".

Comment: @fhm Please add the error details to your question. Maybe you will find more details in the _Error Log_ view.

Comment: I suspect you might have been using old instructions; perhaps even downloading older, deprecated versions.  Like howlger said, "error details" would be helpful. Q: What do you *really* want?  Just NS3?  NS3 with Eclipse/Mercurial?  All of CodeBeamer?  Q: Would you consider re-installing from scratch?